# How to use a temp sequence within a Postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, sequence, postgresql-13

I have some lines of SQL which will take a set of IDs from the same GROUP_ID that are not contiguous (ex. if some rows got deleted) and will make them contiguous again. I wanted to turn this into a function for reusability purposes. The lines work if executed individually but when I try to create the function I get the error

```
ERROR:  relation "id_seq_temp" does not exist  
LINE 10: UPDATE THINGS SET ID=nextval('id_se...
```

If I create a sequence outside of the function and use that sequence in the function instead then the function is created successfully (schema qualified or unqualified). However I felt like creating the temp sequence inside of the function rather than leaving it in the schema was a cleaner solution.

I have seen this question: [Function shows error "relation my_table does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914436/function-shows-error-relation-my-table-does-not-exist)
However, I'm using the public schema and schema qualifying the sequence with `public.` does not seem to help.

I've also seen this question: [How to create a sql function using temp sequences and a SELECT on PostgreSQL8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698546/how-to-create-a-sql-function-using-temp-sequences-and-a-select-on-postgresql8). I probably could use `generate_series` but this adds a lot of complexity that `SERIES` solves such as needing to know how big of a series to generate.

Here is my function, I anonymized some of the names - just in case there's a typo.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reindex_ids(IN BIGINT) RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    CREATE TEMPORARY SEQUENCE id_seq_temp
    MINVALUE 1
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;
    ALTER SEQUENCE id_seq_temp RESTART;
    UPDATE THINGS SET ID=ID+2000 WHERE GROUP_ID=$1;
    UPDATE THINGS SET ID=nextval('id_seq_temp') WHERE GROUP_ID=$1;
$$;
```

Is it possible to use a sequence you create within a function later in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer to question

The reason is that **SQL** functions (`LANGUAGE sql`) are parsed and planned as *one*. All objects used must exist *before* the function runs.

You can switch to **PL/pgSQL**, (`LANGUAGE plpgsql`) which plans each statement on demand. There you can create objects and use them in the next command.

See:

- [Why can PL/pgSQL functions have side effect, while SQL functions can't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004980/why-can-pl-pgsql-functions-have-side-effect-while-sql-functions-cant/51033884#51033884)

Since you are not returning anything, consider a `PROCEDURE`. (`FUNCTION` works, too.)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE reindex_ids(IN bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS ( SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_class
               WHERE  relname = 'id_seq_temp'
               AND    relnamespace = pg_my_temp_schema()
               AND    relkind = 'S') THEN
      ALTER SEQUENCE id_seq_temp RESTART;
   ELSE
      CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE id_seq_temp;
   END IF;

    UPDATE things SET id = id + 2000 WHERE group_id = $1;
    UPDATE things SET id = nextval('id_seq_temp') WHERE group_id = $1;
END
$proc$;
```

Call:

```
CALL reindex_ids(123);
```

This creates your temp sequence if it does not exist already.
If the sequence exists, it is reset. (Remember that temporary objects live for the duration of a session.)
In the unlikely event that some other object occupies the name, an exception is raised.

### Alternative solutions

#### Solution 1

This usually works:

```sql
UPDATE things t
SET    id = t1.new_id
FROM  (
   SELECT pk_id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS new_id
   FROM   things
   WHERE  group_id = $1     -- your input here
   ) t1
WHERE  t.pk_id = t1.pk_id;
```

And only updates each row ***once***, so half the cost.

Replace `pk_id` with your `PRIMARY KEY` column, or any `UNIQUE NOT NULL` (combination of) column(s).

The trick is that the `UPDATE` typically processes rows according to the sort order of the subquery in the `FROM` clause. Updating in ascending order should never hit a duplicate key violation.
And the `ORDER BY` clause of the [window function `row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) imposes that sort order on the resulting set. That's an undocumented implementation detail, so you might want to add an explicit `ORDER BY` to the subquery. But since the behavior of `UPDATE` is undocumented anyway, it still depends on an implementation detail.

You can wrap *that* into a plain SQL function.

#### Solution 2

Consider **not** doing what you are doing at all. Gaps in sequential numbers are typically expected and not a problem. Just live with it. See:

- [Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918552/serial-numbers-per-group-of-rows-for-compound-key/24918964#24918964)

Comment: For anyone looking at this in the future, I do think solution 2 is the best answer and we are transitioning other parts of our codebase which were sensitive to the gaps in sequential numbers away from that. Thanks for the in-depth response it scratched a few itches I had with my problem.